# how to calculate an average after a while loop

Tags: python, while-loop, average

I am trying to get into coding and this is kinda part of the assignments that i need to do to get into the classes.

"Write a program that always asks the user to enter a number. When the user enters the negative number -1, the program should stop requesting the user to enter a number. The program must then calculate the average of the numbers entered excluding the -1."

The while loop i can do... The calculation is what im stuck on.

```
negative = "-1"
passable = "0"
while not passable <= negative:
  passable = input("Write a number: ")
```

I just want to get this to work and a explanation if possible

Comment: Think about what you would need to do if I gave you a list of numbers and asked you to calculate the average "by hand". Then make the code do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out by some of the other answers here, you have to sum up all your answers and divide it by how many numbers you have entered.

However, remember that an `input()` will be a string. Meaning that our `while` loop has to break when it finds the string `'-1'` , and you have to add the `float()` of the number to be able to add the numbers together.

```py
numbers=[]

while True:
    ans=input("Number: ")
    if ans=="-1":
        break
    else:
        numbers.append(float(ans))

print(sum(numbers)/len(numbers))
```

Answer (score 0):

You are assigning strings to your variables, which I don't think is your intention.

This will work:

```
next_input = 0
inputs = []

while True:
    next_input = int(input('Please enter a number:'))
    if next_input == -1:
        break

    else:
        inputs.append(next_input)

return sum(inputs) / len(inputs)
```

First, you need to create a container to store all the entered values in. That's `inputs`, a `list`.

Next, you do need a `while` loop. This is another way of structuring it: a loop that will run indefinitely and a check within it that compares the current input to -1, and terminates the loop with `break` if it does. Otherwise, it appends that input to the `list` of already entered inputs.

After exiting the loop, the average is calculated by taking the sum of all the values in the entered inputs divided by the length of the `list` containing them (i.e. the number of elements in it).

Answer (score 0):

I would initialize a list before asking the user for a number, using a do-while. Then, you add every number to that list unless the number == -1. If it does, then you sum every element in the list and output the average.

Here's pseudocode to help:

```
my_list = []
do
    input_nb = input("Please enter a number: ")
    if(input_nb != -1)
        my_list.add(input_nb)

while (input_nb != -1)

average = sum(my_list) / len(my_list)

print('My average is ' + average)
```